# Outlook Interop Folder.CopyTo Method - Merge Inbox

Tags: powershell, outlook, com-interop, comobject

I'm Trying to copy Mail Items from one mailbox to another, but when i use the Folder.Copy Method to copy the Inbox folder of one mailbox to the other, it's not merge the data but creating Folder Named Inbox1,

Here's my code:

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace  = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("mapi")
$namespace.Logon("Outlook")

$LocalStore = $Namespace.Stores[3]
$RemoteStore = $Namespace.Stores[1]

$LocalFolders = $LocalStore.GetRootFolder().folders
$RemoteFolders = $RemoteStore.GetRootFolder().folders

$RemoteInbox = $RemoteFolders | ? {$_.Name -eq "Inbox"}
$LocalInbox = $LocalFolders | ? {$_.Name -eq "Inbox"}

$RemoteInbox.CopyTo($LocalInbox.Parent)
```

To workaround i can use the Items Copy :

```
Foreach ($Item in $RemoteInbox.Items)
{
$Copy = $Item.Copy()
[void]$Copy.Move($TargetFolder)
}
```

But it's much slower, and if i have subfolders it need special care with extra code,

Search the web with no solution found
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected - if there is already an existing folder with the same name, MAPI will return `MAPI_E_COLLISION` - see [IMAPIFolder::CopyFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815387.aspx).

Outlook detects that error and creates a folder with a unique name.

You can copy items in a batch using [IMAPIFolder.CopyMessages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765921.aspx), but Extended MAPI requires C++ or Delphi. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can use its [RDOItems.CopyMultiple](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) method. You can create an array of entry ids from the source folder using `RDOItems`.[MAPITable.ExecSQL](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm#ExecSQL) and pass it to `RDOItems.CopyMultiple`.

Comment: Do you mean how to convert this to a script that uses Redemption? EWS and MAPI are two different API, you cannot work one through another.

Comment: One of the methods, as i'm not familiar with MAPI